# How to remove an element from a char array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, chararray

is there any way to remove the element in char array I converted from a String?

```
Dim myString As String = "Hello"
Dim charArray As Char() = myString.ToCharArray
```

Your help would be much appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: From the array, not really.  Arrays are immutable.  You can control what goes in to the array, and what comes out again but not so much what is in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-length in .NET. You can set an element to `Nothing` but you cannot remove that element. You can use a collection instead of an array and then you can add, insert and remove items at will, but your example isn't necessarily the best case for that sort of thing, e.g.

```vb
Dim str = "Hello"
Dim chars = New List(Of Char)(str)
```

You can then call `Remove` or `RemoveAt` on that `List` to remove a `Char`. You can then create a new `String` if desired, e.g.

```vb
chars.RemoveAt(2)
str = New String(chars.ToArray())

Console.WriteLine(str)
```

That will display `"Helo"`.

Comment: Thank you for helping, this solve my problem. Thanks a lot.